# Only One Resolver ip

Tags: centos, networking, cpanel, resolv.conf

so i was trying to setup `Cpanel` and i got this problem

it asked me for a Secondary Resolver which i don't have

i tried getting my ip resolver by typing `cat /etc/resolv.conf` in `centos`

and it gave me one single nameserver and one single ip

how can i create/get this secondary resolver.

i'm running `centos` 7 if it matters..

Comment: Type the same address you'd typed for primary nameserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type the same address you'd typed for primary nameserver.